# JSF EL: instanceof reserved but not yet implemented?

Tags: jsf, el, instanceof

I've found the instanceof operator in JSF EL, but it throws an exception when used. It's obviously reserved but not implemented? When will it (probably) be available, if not already in a newer version than JSF 1.2, which I'm currently using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The keyword `instanceof` is indeed reserved in the EL (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnail.html)), but it is still not used in the latest version of EL (2.2), used in JSF 2.x.

Comment: According to http://java.net/jira/browse/JSP_SPEC_PUBLIC-113 it's fixed in JSF 2.1, is it ?